# Is the part pointed out by red arrow a stud?

Tags: sound-proofing, renovation, building-regulations

Consider the following image. Is the part pointed out by red arrow a stud? What is the blue part called?

[image]

Comment: Downvoters... why?

Comment: Maybe because [almost any of thousands of diagrams and articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=wall+framing+diagram&rlz=1C1ZCEB_enUS850US850&oq=wall+framing+diagram&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l7.2765j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) already point this out, and it took ten times as long to write the question as it would have to discover that fact. As such, the question offers little to the community. It's better to ask about a problem or challenge than to use us as a Google proxy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The part pointed at by the blue arrow is a "doubled top plate".

In this case, the wall it's on top of is a load-bearing wall. You can tell because the inner ends of the ceiling joists rest on it. If you pulled that center wall out, there would be nothing to support the top plate and therefore nothing to support the overlapped, inner ends of the joists. Pulling that wall would end up causing collapse of the structure. Handy for demolition, not so much for a simple remodel.

It may well be load-bearing even if the joists run all the way from outer wall to outer wall - that would depend on the height of the joists. Are they tall enough (and therefore strong enough) to span the full width if that wall were removed? To make that determination, though, would require looking at the structural design of the building, and might require the services of a structural engineer for confirmation before removing that center wall.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What kind of remodel regarding this structure is more comlicated than what kind of other structures?

Answer (score 2):

Yep...................that’s a stud.

Comment: @isherwood There was just a red arrow, when I answered. I see they added the blue arrow.